Arguments for vs against filtering Internet Access to legal Websites on University Campus
A university in Germany is using Cisco's Umbrella to filter network access. It affects most areas on the campus used by scientists and students.
The filtering goes beyond what is required by law — Germany has some strict censorship laws — and includes Cisco Umbrella categories such as «hate speech», «adult», etc. which include legal websites. These are, among others, 4chan.org, gab.com, or gab.ai. Websites seems to be added to the categories, as websites that worked a week ago are suddenly blocked. Trying to access a blocked website means you end up at the website of the IT department with the Umbrella category (e.g., «hate speech») and your IP address in the URL. You have the option to contact the IT department and ask for the website to be made available.
I have a strong opinion on the topic, so I am interested in arguments both pro and contra the filtering of legal websites on a university campus.
Note: The issue is explicitly NOT illegal websites. That the university has to comply with the law is a no brainer, it's going beyond the law. The issue is also not that it is also a no-brainer to bypass the filtering with Tor/Vpn/personal hotspots. It's the university preventing access to legal websites.

I mean porn websites are also not illegal, but I completely understand if adult content is blocked - which also happens at my reserach institute in Germany.

Interestingly, the category «Adult» is triggered by Gab AI. As so-called «Uncensored and Unfiltered AI Platform» it can generate nude images, although by that logic you could also block GoogleDocs, as you could write pornographic novels with it.

4chan seems extremely unsurprising to be on their block list, with a reputation not just for smut but for illegal or borderline illegal pornography like revenge and similarly non-consensual porn. And among the non-porn areas a strong pro-Nazi/Nazi-glorifying attitude (both serious and 'edgy' varieties) which is not tolerated in Germany.

It should not be the IT department who makes the decision if a website is compatible with university policy.

Is the university government-funded or owned?

@fraxinus it doesnt matter in Germany, the first amendment argument against filtering is an explicitly American thing

I am not aware of any law which requires a university (or any legal body) to employ a filter when requesting information (uploads may be a different story). Can you link to the law you are referring to?

@AwkwardWhale It's not the First Amendment, the US had a major issue in the 90's. Networks were built with public funds and those attached strict conditions. For example, it's illegal to use government property to run a private business, so a student selling their textbooks on eBay would be committing a crime. Other restrictions include personal use, like streaming videos. US research and education networks had to be rebuilt with funding that didn't carry these stipulations, these were called AUP-free networks.

There is freedom of opinion guaranteed in the German constitution. That doesn't mean that the government has to provide you with a network (at a university) where you can watch porn or look at otherwise questionable webpages. It means the government can't interfere with you doing this on your own dime.

@Marianne013 The top levels of the IT department should be part of discussions that establish university policies with respect to technology.

@DanielWessel The Google Docs comparison is missing the point. It's not what a user could theoretically do with a tool, it's what it is commonly used for. And given that gab.ai specifically advertises itself as "uncensored AI" you don't need to be a conspiracy theorist to speculate that users will gravitate towards this platform to do things other mainstream platforms don't allow you to do.

@xLeitix Gab.AI isn't "uncensored AI": it's explicitly censored, with phrases such as "Avoid any discussion or implication that suggests a person can change their biological sex from male to female" in its prompt.

Just a funny story, from Norway: if I happen to feel a need for visiting pirate bay, my ISP at home blocks it, so I go through my university. But when I want to look around on sci-hub, that's blocked by the university, so I do that from home... ¯\(ツ)/¯

Arguments for filtering:

Even content that is not explicitly illegal can be harmful, degrading or demeaning, so it is a benefit to filter it out.

Hate speech, adult content etc. are not necessary for research or teaching.

University campuses actually do not only have adult visitors. There are students younger than 18 years, or visitors even younger. The university has a duty to protect these vulnerable users.

Why a particular website falls into one category, and why this specific category or this specific website should be filtered, will of course be specific to the website or category, so there may be additional arguments to filter this one website.

Thanks to Todd Wilcox for this one: even legal and in itself unobjectionable content can be a bandwidth problem. Todd:

I've worked in environments the USA where during the NBA "March Madness" tournament and NFL draft season, users accessing websites related to those events consumed an inordinate amount of the available bandwidth causing a negative impact on all other traffic. We had to amend the technology use policy and restrict access to sports content to make sure work could continue efficiently.



Arguments against filtering:

Who decides what "hate speech" or an "adult website" is? Yes, as you write, one can have recourse... but if the admin decides against you, you pretty much have no further option. Better not to give anyone this power.
There are false positives in all these blacklists, i.e., innocuous websites that get filtered in error.
The vast majority of users are indeed adult.
Free speech and the free flow of information are a value in themselves, especially in academia, which is premised on a free exchange of ideas - and the first step in suppressing ideas is often to label them harmful.
This kind of content can actually indeed be the subject of research and teaching. Picture a seminar on political hate speech. Does the instructor need to tell students to access examples on their personal devices in a coffee shop WLAN?

Of course, the university ultimately owns the infrastructure and is under no obligation to provide access at all, or not to censor specific content.

The very last point is extremely important. The university network is meant to enable you to work, not for your entertainment (I remember the days of napster being blocked, in the US that is).

not providing internet access at all in 2024 in an university is somewhat pushing it

@Marianne013 indeed looking at a few user agreements for German universities they’re quite explicit in stating that they’re providing network access for strictly educational purposes

In practice for this reason dormitories have a seperate network and user agreement for the students living there

"the university ultimately owns the infrastructure" So do internet providers serving homes, and they aren't free to censor as they please (at least I hope so). I'd certainly agree that universities have less obligations, but ownership is not the reason.

@Stefan Ownership is the issue actually. This was a problem in the US in the 90's. University networks on the state, and nationwide scale get government funding. As public properties, a number of conditions attached. For example, you can't use government property for private gain, so selling your textbooks on eBay from the library is illegal. Incidental personal use is generally OK, but dorms where users regularly stream movies exceeds that. This isn't an issue with commercial ISPs obviously, and US RENs had to rebuild with funding without these stipulations, so called AUP free networks.

Haha you build some tension in your answer. I'm not sure it is appropriate or on purpose but the sentence "Hate speech, adult content etc. are not necessary for research or teaching." of course immediately makes you think "Depends on what you research." Of course you go into that in the second half of the answer.

In the US many universities are government-run and are therefore bound by first amendment law (and many private universities at least tacitly agree to be so bound). I suspect they would have an extremely difficult time arguing for limiting access to otherwise legal materials. There might even be illegal material for which they would have a difficult time justifying access limitations.

@AwkwardWhale Different kind of networks for student accommodation are not unheard of in the UK either.

I can think of at least one more reason: Safe entertainment content can sometimes be a major problem for other network traffic. I've worked in environments the USA where during the NBA "March Madness" tournament and NFL draft season, users accessing websites related to those events consumed an inordinate amount of the available bandwidth causing a negative impact on all other traffic. We had to amend the technology use policy and restrict access to sports content to make sure work could continue efficiently.

@ToddWilcox: thank you, that is a great point! I edited it in, with proper attribution to you.

"The vast majority of users are indeed adult." – OTOH, with the abolishment of mandatory military service and the shortening of typical school duration from 13 years to 12, a significant portion of first semester students are minors.

@JörgWMittag: yes, which I mentioned, from personal experience. So a significant portion of incoming students (not a majority) will be underage, but by the second year, almost all students should be legally (in Germany) adults, plus of course all non-student users. Note that with many Bundesländer moving back to 13 years schooling, this effect will decline in the future.

The most probable decisive argument "for":
Managing a limited resource in a political manner.

Managing a big network is a challenge
Managing a big network with a lot of less literate users is a pain in the butt
Managing a huge network with a lot of less literate users who cannot be compelled to cooperate is a hell.

Left alone, in a typical university network, the entertainment traffic quickly overtakes the available bandwidth, making the network barely usable. (The malware traffic is quick to follow.)
When pressed to do something, the network admins are usually not in a position to simply increase the network capacity (and even if they are, this just means more porn), so they start filtering.
Once the filtering is in place, the content to be filtered becomes a political matter and the decision-making gets in the hands of the most vocal stakeholders.
On the other hand, the general result from filtering is a transition from an useless nerwork to more or less usable one so most users welcome the change.
The most important argument "against":
Filtering cannot be done right.
It either compromises the end user security (when done by decrypting the traffic), or is very, very coarse, or both.
Most filttering software is crap on its own right and this does not prevent it from being expensive and a resource hog.

Should 'literate' be read as 'technically literate' in this context?

@Anyon not necessarily, social, cultural and even local language literacy are related as well

“Left alone, in a typical university network, the entertainment traffic quickly overtakes the available bandwidth, making the network barely usable.” — do you have a source for this?  This seems surprising to me (I’d have expected entertainment traffic to be significant but not overwhelming), so I’d be interested to see a source, or at least (if you don’t have a public source) background on how confidently you believe this and why.

Not sure about a public source and it is not trivial to research the matter anymore because everything is encrypted these days. I have personal experience in this regard both as a user, as well as someone involved in the network administration. In the recent years, the problem is only a little bit easier because of the availability of a cheap cellphone internet and the relative unpopularity of the bittorrent and likes. Facebook/X/Instagram still rule in the upstream pipe, but it is now possible to brute force the problem with gigabits, at least in a corporate/govmnt context. Uni's - not really

So I'm interpreting this based on US and what I'm able to find.
On a tangent, according to NYCLU, the general idea is that private institutions (like with any other private entity) has the right to restrict the first Amendment - to that end I'd say it would also result in them restricting what you do and how you do it.  Public institutions will lean towards not being restricted, and I'd say that generally, they cannot restrict you in other manners either.  That being said, many places are allowed to still, within reason, choose how and when one can express themselves, so to that end, even if it can't be restricted, it can be funneled within reason.
As for filtering the internet itself beyond what is allowed by law...
For Filtering

You can request specific sites to be allowed, so in the event you've got a valid reason to access a blocked site for research, you can provide the reason and get it approved.

The college has a right to block what they believe is a risk to the network as a whole.  While you're on their network, if there's a risk of something getting through that can propagate to other devices, both student and college-owned, then that's a problem.  Sure, there are firewalls and anti-virus software, but nothing beats avoiding security threats like not putting yourself in the position to possibly get one.  Yeah, you can argue "b-but then don't use the internet lol! except there needs to be a good tradeoff; obviously the internet is a lot more important, and there's plenty of legitimate sites that don't pose a risk.

A school is a place for learning, not to socialize or have fun.

Sure, maybe you can have two networks, one is locked down and the other is open-use, and isolate them somehow, but the work involved may not be worth it.

If you wish to socialize or use the internet for recreation, we have cell phones, many of which can have a hotspot feature.  Want to do non-essential tasks online?  Should be on your time and your dime.


Against filtering

If it's a public institution, one can argue you're stifling free speech/expression.

If it's guaranteed that there are no people under the age of majority (or just no one under 18), then as a legal adult, students should have access to the internet, period, at least as unfiltered as allowed by law, obviously.

If the school's IT team is incompetent at best, then who knows how long you have to wait to unblock something, if you fall into a fringe case?  And all too often I hear of professors that choose to not care      about what is preventing someone from doing something, even if that thing is outside of the student's control; which might be a good analogue to life, except where in life there's often lots of alternatives - often times a professor has a "my way or the highway" attitude.



An important distinction here is whether the university is only a space of teaching and learning or whether it also contains dormatories that are the primary residence for students.
If the university does not contain dormatories it can be seen as similar to a place of work and the internet access it provides is related to studying and learning. There is no real reason why the university should give you access to the internet for your personal entertainement. This can actually be a lot more restrictive than what you describe and could also block access to gaming, movies or sports coverage. Universities usually don't act that restrictive but they could.
There are some researchers that need access to websites that are usually restricted, researching hate-speed or computer security and a few other topics. That is what the option to contact the IT department is for.
If on the other hand the university is also the primary place of residence for some students, it should grant access to the internet that is more similar to what you would get when renting an apartment. It should still restrict to legal websites, but otherwise be open. It should also provide you with privacy on what you are browsing.

Content filtering is "strongly discouraged" by Eduroam policies. From the Eduroam compliance statement:

eduroam SPs [Service providers] are based on SP local policies. However, modifying the content of user connections (e.g., access lists or firewall filter rules to deny arbitrary ports or application-layer proxies) is strongly discouraged and MUST be reported to the respective RO [Roaming operator, the country-level Eduroam authorities].

